# Sum of elements in foreach yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have this in my gridview:

```
[
    'value' => function ($data) {
        $summ = 0;
        $str = 0;
        foreach($data->itemsOrder as $request) {
            $str .= $request->order_items_quantity;
            $summ += $str;
        }

        return $summ;
    },
],
```

I get something like that '123' in column cell, but not '6'. How Could I get sum of elements?

Comment: change $str .= $request->order_items_quantity; to $str = $request->order_items_quantity;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  gridview [
            'value' => function ($data) {
                $summ = 0;
                $str = 0;
                foreach($data->itemsOrder as $request) {
                    //$str .= $request->order_items_quantity; //this means you are concating string each time which you dont need to do
                    $str = $request->order_items_quantity;
                    $summ += $str;
                }

                return $summ;
            },

        ],
```

Hope you get the meaning of `.` in php

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
 gridview [
            'value' => function ($data) {
                $summ = 0;
                $str = 0;
                foreach($data->itemsOrder as $request) {
                    $summ +=$request->order_items_quantity;
                }

                return $summ;
            },

        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are concatenating string and not adding number.

So replace `$str .= $request->order_items_quantity;`

with

```
$str += floatval($request->order_items_quantity);
```

or if order_items_quantity is an integer

```
$str += intval($request->order_items_quantity);
```